# SELinux installation

Tags: ubuntu, selinux

I am trying to download SELinux on an Ubuntu 11.04 using `apt-get`.

When I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install selinux
```

I got the following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   selinux : PreDepends: grub-pc but it is not installable
>   E: Broken packages

I then downloaded `selinux-utils`, `selinux-basics`.

After this, I checked for the `selinux` file under `/etc/sysconfig` but I couldn't find it.

Also, when I tried

```
$ setenforce 1
```

it returns:

> setenforce: SELinux is disabled

What are the dependencies? What should I download? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't GRUB (bootloader). I guess SELinux requires some changes in kernel so install your system with GRUB. Than installing SELinux just by 'apt-get install selinux' is correct.

Comment: What changes in the kernel are required? SELinux is baked into the kernel for all Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: Few years ago there were just several Linux distro that had been supporting SELinux. Now, 2017, it is natively present in most of well-known distros, I think. Just make sure if it is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Running SELinux under a Linux distribution requires three things: An SELinux enabled kernel, SELinux Userspace tools and libraries, and SELinux Policies.  I'm guessing either your Kernel was compiled without the SELinux option enabled, and/or an issue related to your bootloader (grub-pc).  [This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/SELinux.txt) is from the Kernel docs.

> > If you want to use SELinux, chances are you will want to use the distro-provided policies, or install the latest reference policy
> >     release from  http://oss.tresys.com/projects/refpolicy
>
> However, if you want to install a dummy policy for testing, you can do
>   using 'mdp' provided under scripts/selinux.  Note that this requires
>   the selinux userspace to be installed - in particular you will need
>   checkpolicy to compile a kernel, and setfiles and fixfiles to label
>   the filesystem.
>
> 1. Compile the kernel with selinux enabled.
> 2. Type 'make' to compile mdp.
> 3. Make sure that you are not running with
>       SELinux enabled and a real policy.  If
>       you are, reboot with selinux disabled
>       before continuing.
> 4. Run install_policy.sh:       cd scripts/selinux      sh install_policy.sh
>
> Step 4 will create a new dummy policy valid for your kernel, with a
>   single selinux user, role, and type. It will compile the policy, will
>   set your SELINUXTYPE to dummy in /etc/selinux/config, install the
>   compiled policy as 'dummy', and relabel your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to uninstall AppArmor because it may conflict with SELinux:

Remove apparmor
Remove apparmor-util